# JavaScript Arrow function not working as expected

Tags: javascript, referenceerror

```
const showLocation = () => {
    const locationName = document.getElementById('locationName')
    const selectedElement = document.querySelector('input[name="selected_location"]:checked').value
    locationName.innerHTML = selectedElement
}
```

The HTML

```
          <div class="bottom" onchange="showLocation()">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="radio" id="selected_location_nyr" name="selected_location" value="NEW_YORK_ROOT">
                <label for="selected_location_nyr">New York Root</label>
              </li>
```

The error I get is

(index):120

```
   Uncaught ReferenceError: showLocation is not defined
at HTMLDivElement.onchange ((index):120:61)
```

The JavaScript declaration

```
<script src="javascript/test-123.js" defer></script>
<title>Document</title>
</head>
```

It's in my head tag but I added defer to it so that the page will continue to load.

Comment: Where did you define that `const showLocation` and how did you include the script in your html page?

Comment: @Bergi I added the code to show my JavaScript declaration

Comment: When do you expect a `change` event to fire on a `<div>`?

Comment: So when the user clicks the radio, I want the text from the radio to appear in an input type=text element. The Id of this element is 'locationName'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments I edit the answer, I guess what you need is something like this: Click on the Run Snippet to see the result

```js
const radioInput = document.querySelector("#selected_location_nyr");
const locationName = document.querySelector("#selected_location");

radioInput.addEventListener("change", showLocation);

function showLocation() {
  locationName.value = radioInput.value;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label for="selected_location_nyr">New York Root</label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            id="selected_location_nyr"
            name="selected_location"
            value="NEW_YORK_ROOT"
          />
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="selected_location">Selected Location</label>
          <input type="text" name="selected_location" id="selected_location" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

The section below shows how you can achieve the above functionality for multiple `radio` inputs

```js
const radioInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');

radioInputs.forEach((radio) => {
  radio.addEventListener("change", showLocation);
});

const locationName = document.querySelector("#selected_location");

function showLocation() {
  locationName.value = this.value;
}
```

```html
    <div><input type="radio" name="select_location" value="1" /> 1</div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="select_location" value="2" /> 2</div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="select_location" value="3" /> 3</div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="select_location" value="4" /> 4</div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label for="selected_location">Selected Location</label>
          <input type="text" name="selected_location" id="selected_location" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: `const` declarations are hoisted, but the error message says it's not available at all not just not initialised.

Comment: do I need to change my HTML? I copied the 2 additional lines and the same exception is thrown. How would I initialize it? do I say "let x = ''"

Comment: @softwareisfun I edited the my answer based on your comments, check it again

Comment: @TaghiKhavari Thanks but why did you target the radio by ID? I had only pasted 1 for demonstration purposes. I have 10 radio buttons. When I modified your code to const radioInput = document.querySelector('selected_location');

I get an error. If I use your code, it only attaches to the first radio input? Do I need to copy and paste this for every radio input?

Comment: @softwareisfun I add another section for multiple inputs

Comment: @TaghiKhavari thank you very much. I appreciate your help! I found a similar solution but yours is much more elegant. I ended up with 30+ inputs and added the onchange to the HTML tag. One last thing, is there an easy way to get the value of the label to be displayed instead of the radio button? I thought that the value would show the label value